# Error in if statement of Singly Linked List Program

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am working on `SinglyLinkedList` program in which I have written all the methods. There is a method `deleteAtGiven(int t)`, which throws an exception `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the variable t is less than 0 or t is greater than or equal to the size but it is giving me an error of Unreachable statement.

I tried to write it in the else-if statement and invert the else=if statement but it is not working.

Here is my Code

```
public E deleteAtGiven(int t){
    if(isEmpty()) return null;
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("List is Empty");
    else if (t<0 ||t>=size()){ 
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid Position");
   }
}
```

It should throw an exception.

Comment: You have two statements in your if statement body: `return null` and throwing the exception. If you want to use the form of `if` without braces, each condition must contain only one statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we change the line breaks and indenting of your code to match Java standards, I suspect that you'll see what the issue is:

```
public E deleteAtGiven(int t){
    if(isEmpty()) 
        return null;
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("List is Empty");
    else if (t<0 ||t>=size()){ 
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid Position");
   }
}
```

The throw directive is not controlled by the if statement.  Instead, the throw happens every time the method is called, regardless of whether or not the if statement is triggered.  That causes all code following the throw to be unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public E deleteAtGiven(int t){
        if(isEmpty()) return null;
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("List is Empty");
        else if (t<0 ||t>=size()) 
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid Position");
         }
```

In the above code, `isEmpty()`, checks whether the linked list is empty or not. If so, it returns a `null` value.
If the linkedlist is not empty then the statement just below the if condition is executed.
Here it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.
Hence, the code in the else if part will never execute, which results in the statements just below the throw statement to be unreachable.

As per my understanding of what you're trying to do, you'll have to do something like this:

```
public E deleteAtGiven(int t){
        if(isEmpty()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("List is Empty");
        }
        else if (t<0 ||t>=size()){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid Position");
        }else{
           // rest logic resides here.
        }
     }
```

Explaination :
If the linked list is already empty, the just throw the empty exception. Else, if the index of the element is invalid, then throw exception "Invalid position".

Answer (score 0):

You can not use throw after return, it will not be reachable,

```
public E deleteAtGiven(int t){
    if(isEmpty())
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("List is Empty");
    else if (t<0 ||t>=size()) 
          throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid Position");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you cant make else if the if don't reach. if you return than the exception will not reach. if you throw exception the function will brake automatically so you can do it like that

```
    public E deleteAtGiven(int t) {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("List is Empty");
    else if (t < 0 || t >= size()) 
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid Position");

    else return null;
}
```

and when it pass all the cases you return null or whatever you want if not pass the cases it will run an exception